# Thread-Safe Hide form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, show-hide

I'm trying to make a "loading..." form in a DLL with a simple animation using a BackgroundWorker (**netMessageInWait**).

I have a **Show** function that load the form, set all texts and run the BackgroundWorker

```
Public Sub Show(ByVal WorkingArea As Rectangle, ByVal Title As String, ByVal Message As String)
     With wait
        If (wait.InvokeRequired) Then
            wait.Invoke(Sub()
                            With .lblTitle
                                .Text = Title
                            End With
                            With .lblMessage
                                .Text = Message
                            End With
                        End Sub)
        Else
            With .lblTitle
                .Text = Title
            End With
            With .lblMessage
                .Text = Message
            End With
        End If
    End With

    If (Not backWorker.IsBusy) Then
        Dim args As New ShowArgumentType
        args.WorkingArea = WorkingArea
        args.Title = Title
        args.Message = Message

        backWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync(args)
    End If    
End Sub
```

And the **Clear** function that stop the BackgroundWorker

```
Public Sub ClearMessage()
    Try
        CancelWork = True
        backWorker.CancelAsync()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The **BackgroundWorker_DoWork()** that show fisically the form and wait for the **ClearMessage**

```
Private Sub backWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backWorker.DoWork
    Dim args As ShowArgumentType = DirectCast(e.Argument, ShowArgumentType)

    wait.Show()

    While True
        Application.DoEvents()
        If (CancelWork Or backWorker.CancellationPending) Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

And then the **BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted()** that Hide the form

```
Private Sub backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles backWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    CancelWork = False

    Call ShowHideForm_ThreadSafe(wait, False) ' HERE THE PROBLEM

    Debug.Print("Work completed")
End Sub
```

Ok...wath I'm not understanding is why I try to hide the form with the function below the program freez at the BeginInvoke...

```
Private Sub ShowHideForm_ThreadSafe(ByVal pform As Form, _
                                    ByVal pshow As Boolean)
    If pform.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New ShowHideForm_Delegate(AddressOf ShowHideForm_ThreadSafe)



        pform.BeginInvoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[pform], [pshow]})


    Else
        If (pshow) Then
            pform.Show()
        Else
            pform.Hide()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Please help me! How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: This is chronically done the wrong way around.  The BGW thread is horribly unsuitable to display UI.  Have the BGW thread do whatever the UI thread is doing now and leave the UI thread available to display the form.  Show the form before you call RunWorkerAsync().  Hiding or closing the progress form now becomes trivial from the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant so how can I show/hide windows form in a separated thread?